# Almost Surely Convergence

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

I'm studying for an exam at the moment, and this type of questions has just got me stumped to the point where I need a step-by-step walkthrough.

More specifically, I've got one problem I just can't get past:

> Let $(X_n)$ be i.d.d random variables. $X_n$ ~ $Exp(1)$.
>   Denote $Z_n = min\left\{X_1, X_2,..., X_n\right\}$.
>   Prove that $Z_n$ converges almost surely to $0$.

I'm guessing the first step is to find $Z_n$'s distribution function, but I don't know what to do next. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The first thing to prove is that the minimum of $n$ independent identical exponentially distributed random variables with parameter $1$ is itself exponentially distributed with parameter $n$. In fact, the parameters can even be different, say $\lambda_1,\dotsc,\lambda_n$; as long we keep independence then the minimum is distributed like $\exp(\sum \lambda_i)$. Knowing this, it should be easier to show $Z_n \to 0$ almost surely.

Comment: Actually, my problem is how to show $Z_n → 0$ almost surely. :(

Comment: I understand. If you know the distribution of $Z_n$ then you should be able to finish Lord Shark's answer below.

Answer (score 2):

The sequence $Z_n$ is nonnegative and decreasing: $Z_1\ge Z_2\ge Z_3\ge
\cdots\ge0$. For it to fail to converge to zero, there will be $N\in \Bbb N$
with $Z_k\ge 1/N$ for all $k$ (equivalently, $X_k\ge 1/N$ for all $k$). What's the probability of that?

Comment: Can you write it more specifically? I understand your point but I don't know how to express it clearly! Thanks!

Comment: @Sophie what exactly are you having trouble expressing clearly? What you need to do is calculate $P(Z_n \geq 1/N)$ and show this $\to 0$ as $N \to \infty$. If calculating the probability before taking the limit is giving you trouble then I infer you are confused about the distribution of $Z_n$, which my first comment addresses and you should reread carefully. If not, then you need to specify what is impeding your work.

Comment: @Sophie I've amplified my solution a bit: the point is to compute the probability of the event $\{X_k\ge 1/N \textrm{ for all }k\in\mathbb{N}\}$.

Comment: I got it! Thanks.